# Why is this javascript object code not working?

Tags: javascript, object, for-loop

```
var house = new Object(floors: "4", color:"red", windows:"lots", bathrooms:"3");
var result ="";
for (var i in house)
{
    result +="house." + i + " is " + house.i + ".<br />";
}
document.body.innerHTML += result;
```

I want to output `house.floors is 4.<br />house.color is red.<br />`and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Object constructor doesn't work like that. Use an object literal instead.

```
var house = { floors: "4", color:"red", windows:"lots", bathrooms:"3" }
```

Additionally `house.i` will reference the `i` property, not the property with the name that is stored in the string `i`, you want `house[i]`.

Answer (score 2):

Curly brackets:

```
var house = {floors: "4", color:"red", windows:"lots", bathrooms:"3"};
```

There's rarely a need (in fact I can't think of a reason) to use an explicit Object constructor call; just use `{}` for a new, plain, empty Object instance, and `[]` for a new, plain, empty Array instance.  For objects with initial properties, use the "name:value" syntax like you did (except in curly brackets).